# Extract values from a set of checkboxes

Tags: php, forms

I have been having a whale of a time trying to figure this one out.  I have a script that takes a form post from my website and sends the data in a nicely formatted email to my email address.  The problem I'm having is that the form has to calculate a running total while users are filling it out, part of which comes from the value of the select boxes as one variable and the value of the checkboxes as another, added together to form the grand total.  In order to make this work, I have to have a hidden checkbox in my form with a value of '0' that is marked as checked.  Because of this, the array I send to phpmailer always has an index count of at least 1.  When no other options are checked and just the hidden checkbox is checked, it returns "No Option Selected" perfectly in the email.  When I have one other option checked or multiple options checked, it sends them correctly to the form with a 
 tag so that they are displayed in row order.  The problem is that no matter what I do, the very last $optiontype repeats and displays in my email form twice.

[screenshot of email form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRrs7.png)

I think it's the last conditional statement in my code that's the problem.

if (isset($_POST['optiontype'])) {
$arraycount = count($_POST['optiontype']);

```
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($_POST['optiontype']); $index++) {
        $value = $_POST['optiontype'][$index];
        
        if ($value == '0' && $arraycount == 1) {
            $value_text = 'No Options Selected';
        }  
        if ($value == '70') {
            $value_text = '$70 Green Plus';
        }
        if ($value == '75') {
            $value_text = '$75 Subterranean Termite Treatment';
        }
        if ($value == '50') {
            $value_text = '$50 Freezer-Standalone';
        }
        if ($value == '25') {
            $value_text = '$25 Wet Bar Refrigerator/2nd Refrigerator';
        }
        if ($value == '150') {
            $value_text = '$150 Pool/Spa Combo';
        }
        if ($value == '150+0') {
            $value_text = '$150 Additional Pool or Spa';
        }
        if ($value == '300') {
            $value_text = '$300 Salt Water Pool (Includes Pool/Spa Combo)';
        }
        if ($value == '100') {
            $value_text = '$100 Well Pump';
        }
        if ($value == '75+0') {
            $value_text = '$75 Septic System/Sewage Ejector Pump & Septic Tank Pumping';}
        if ($value == '90') {
            $value_text = '$90 External Water Line Repair';
        }
        if ($value == '195') {
            $value_text = '$195 External Water Line + Sewer & Septic Line Repair';
        }  
        
        if ($index < $arraycount) {
            $optiontype .= $value_text . "<br>";
        } else {
            $optiontype .= $value_text;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so looking into the future this code will be VERY difficult to maintain especially when you change prices. I would instead put all your products into an array (or DB would be better) and do something like this. `$products = ['50' => '$50 Freezer-Standalone', '75' => '$75 Subterranean Termite Treatment']; $value_text = $products[$value];`

Comment: you could even check to see if the product exists first in the array, basically the if/else code will prove to be difficult to maintain

Comment: Here's hopefully a good tutorial showing how to use multiple select boxes with PHP - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php/

Comment: What @hppycoder said! This question really has nothing at all to do with PHPMailer, so I edited out references to it. You could simplify your script by making use of [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for the loop, and [`match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) for your comparisons, but all those prices and names should be in a database anyway.

Comment: I appreciate all the comments and agree... but we only change our prices about every 4 years and the entirety of our product catalog is only about 50 items.  This was supposed to be just a simple convenience for my customers, and for me, to make sure I get the required information to enter an order.  At this time, I really just want to know why that last option keeps repeating...it's hurting my brain, I've tried every condition I can think of.

Comment: We told you how to resolve ... [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is the right way to iterate through `$_POST['optiontype']`. I can show you in an answer below if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the comments above I've worked in a small example which will have a variable named `$options` that's a string from the array options found in the `$_POST['optiontype']`

```php
<?php
$products = [
    '70' => '$70 Green Plus',
    '75' => '$75 Subterranean Termite Treatment',
    '50' => '$50 Freezer-Standalone',
    '25' => '$25 Wet Bar Refrigerator/2nd Refrigerator',
    '150' => '$150 Pool/Spa Combo',
    '150+0' => '$150 Additional Pool or Spa',
    '300' => '$300 Salt Water Pool (Includes Pool/Spa Combo)',
    '100' => '$100 Well Pump',
    '75+0' => '$75 Septic System/Sewage Ejector Pump & Septic Tank Pumping',
    '90' => '$90 External Water Line Repair',
    '195' => '$195 External Water Line + Sewer & Septic Line Repair'
];

$values = [];

// this should come from your real $_POST but I just made it up
// showing an element named notFound as it will be ignored
$_POST = ['optiontype' => ['70', '300', '75+0', 'notFound']];

if (isset($_POST['optiontype'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['optiontype'] as $option) {
        if(!empty($products[$option])) {
            $values[] = $products[$option];
        }
    }
}

$options = implode("<br>", $values);

var_dump($options);
```

Output:

```
string(127) "$70 Green Plus<br>$300 Salt Water Pool (Includes Pool/Spa Combo)<br>$75 Septic System/Sewage Ejector Pump & Septic Tank Pumping"
```

Comment: That's amazing and very neat code!  Thank you so much, I will give it a try now.

Comment: A lot has been said about my code, might be a first that it's been called "amazing" or "neat". It should work for you, just make sure you take out my setting of `$_POST`. I want ed you to see what it *should* be doing if your form is correct

Comment: Oh and you can also use the `$products` array when you display your checkboxes. That way you just update one time in your application and it goes everywhere.